# Is it natural to say "a content" when talking about a picture?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

A guy described the following picture in this way

> The picture shows a beach, with many small
>   boats in the water nearby.

[image]

That's good, at least to me.

And then he said

> Simple summaries like this make it easy to understand the general **contents** of the picture.

Where he used the word "contents".

Cambridge Dictionary gives some definitions

> the articles or parts contained in a magazine or book, with the number of the page they begin on
>
> the amount of a particular substance contained in something
>
> everything that is contained within something

I guess the last one fits with this situation, any object within the picture, the question is

is it natural to refer to boats or any boat in the picture as **a content** in the picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not natural.  *contents* in that definition is never divided into singular bits of content.  Similarly we talk about the contents of a suitcase, but would never say one shirt was "a content" of that suitcase.